# Jquery as oppose of using button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was assigned to do a photo gallery.

A big picture (1000x1000) in the middle, three little thumbnails picture(200x200) below it.

I was given this useful function

```
getBigImg(thumbnail); // Returns big image
```

We assume the CSS is already given for us and we do not need to worry.

```
<div class="big image">
    <img src="big picture"/>
</div>

<div class = "thumbnails">
    <div id="placement1>   img src thumbnail 1  </div>
    <div id="placement2>   img src thumbnail 2  </div>
    <div id="placement3>   img src thumbnail 3  </div>
</div>
```

What I did is simple create 3 copies of the .HTML and do  infront of each of the thumbnails. Whenever the user click on the image it will redirects to the .html where the big image is big image of the thumbnail.

I was told I can save all this hassle by using JQuery. What are they referring to?

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like [this example](http://designsnack.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-jquery-gallery/):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".galImg").click(function() {
            var image = $(this).attr("rel");
            $('#feature').fadeOut('slow');
            $('#feature').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
            $('#feature').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this HTML:  little bug fixes

```
<div class="big image">
    <img class="bigImage" src="big picture"/>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <div id="placement1" >   <img src="thumbnail1" />  </div>
    <div id="placement2" >   <img src="thumbnail2" />  </div>
    <div id="placement3" >   <img src="thumbnail3" />  </div>
</div>
```

and add this to your HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.thumbnails > div', function(){
    var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.bigImage').attr('src', img);
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: ^ I don't understand. Why didn't you use getBigImg(thumbnail)? Maybe I don't understand your code. The purpose of this script is whenever the user click on one of the thumbnails, the bigImage will become getBigImg(thumbnail they clicked).

Comment: you asked for a  jQuery solution.  Did you run the code that I provided to see what it does? Each time a user clicks one of the images on the bottom - the big image in the center will become the image that the user just clicked. I think if you did it would be exactly what you wanted.

Comment: ^ thanks. For the record I didn't downvote the post.

Comment: I think the other guy downvoted because I commented about him stealing code and being too lazy to change the id's .  If you are using 3 separate HTML pages to accomplish this - then that is completely unnecessary.  Just try the code that I provided, paste it in and see how it works.